# _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks not printing memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I have following code snipped. Its not printing memory present in below program.
I ran in debug mode. To verify debug mode, I have added _DEBUG macro and its printing 20.
Can anyone please help here
Tool : Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) - LTSC 17.4

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>

#include <iostream>

#ifndef _DEBUG                  /* For RELEASE builds */
#define  PI 3.14
#else                           /* For DEBUG builds   */
#define  PI 22
#endif


int main()
{
   // int* ptr = new int[5];
    int* ptr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        ptr[i] = (i+1) * 10;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        std::cout <<"\n"<< ptr[i];
    }
    std::cout << "\n" << PI;
    _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG);
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
}
```

Output :
10
20
30
40
50
PI : 22

Hi,
I have following code snipped. Its not printing memory present in below program.
I ran in debug mode. To verify debug mode, I have added _DEBUG macro and its printing 20.
Can anyone please help here

Comment: You never check the return value from `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks`. It will most probably be `1`, meaning that there are memory leaks.

Comment: Look in the output window. `Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
C:\dev\Test\Test.cpp(47) : {152} normal block at 0x00000253D9F66E90, 20 bytes long.
 Data: <            (   > 0A 00 00 00 14 00 00 00 1E 00 00 00 28 00 00 00 
Object dump complete.`

Comment: You can redirect the output to a file like `stderr` if you like. There's an example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/crtsetreportmode?view=msvc-170